# Pandas read DataFrame with table schema

Tags: python, pandas, jsonschema

I have notice that pandas has an option to export the [table schema](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#table-schema) of a dataset. The problem is that it seems that you can use this table schema only if you are exporting and reading with the `to_json` and `read_json` methods.

Is there a more generic strategy to read a Dataframe with a specified schema in pandas? For example use `read_csv` and then casting the columns with a specified table schema or jsonschema.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Closest I see is if/when you use the Dataframe to write you can specify: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63780643/496289