# Bigquery parquet file treats list<string> as list<int32> when empty array is passed

Tags: python, google-bigquery, parquet, pyarrow

I have a large nested terabyte sized jsonl(s) which I am converting to parquet files and writing to a have partitioned google cloud storage bucket.

The issue is as follows. One of the nested fields is a list of string
ideally the schema for this field I expect is `billing_code_modifier: list<item: string>`, but there is a rare case the sometimes the length of the list is 0 for all records in which case pandas writes the `billing_code_modifier: list<item: null>`

This causes an issue since the third party tool  [bigquery] which is being used to read these parquet files fail to read these due to inconsistent schema expecting list not list [it defaults empty arrays to int32 , blame google not me]

How does one get around this. Is there a way to specify the schema while writing parquet files.
Since I am dealing with a bucket I cannot write an empty parquet and then add the data to the file in 2 separate write operations as GCP does not allow you to modify files only overwrite

Answer (score 1):

For Pandas you can specify an Arrow schema as a kwarg which should provide the correct schema.  See [Pyarrow apply schema when using pandas to_parquet()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850667/pyarrow-apply-schema-when-using-pandas-to-parquet) for details.